# Find average value of function over tetrahedron

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The question is: Find the average value of $f(x, y, z) = x + y + z$ over the tetrahedron with vertices $(0, 0, 0)$, $(1, 0, 0)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, and $(1, 1, 1)$.

I know how to find average value but am having trouble finding the bounds of integration for this problem. I ended up adding the point $(1,1,0)$ to make it easier to split the shape up and then subtracted the extra volume. But that method seems kind of inefficient. Does anyone have any idea of a better way to integrate this.

Edit: I know there's a very similar question to this that's already been answered, but my problem lies specifically in the vertices assigned in this problem. So knowing general methodology doesn't help me.